# How to read file in pyspark with "]|[" delimiter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The data looks like this:

`pageId]|[page]|[Position]|[sysId]|[carId
 0005]|[bmw]|[south]|[AD6]|[OP4`

There are atleast 50 columns and millions of rows.

I did try to use below code to read:

`dff = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "]|[").load(trainingdata+"part-00000")`

it gives me following error:

`IllegalArgumentException: u'Delimiter cannot be more than one character: ]|['`

Answer (score 7):

you can use more than one character for delimiter in RDD

you can try this code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

input = sc.textFile("yourdata.csv").map(lambda x: x.split(']|['))

print input.collect()
```

you can transform the RDD to DataFrame (if you want), using `toDF()` function, and do not forget to specify the schema if you want to do that

Answer (score -1):

Try with escape sequence

```
dff = (sqlContext.read
                 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                 .option("delimiter", "\\]\\|\\[")
                 .load(trainingdata+"part-00000")
```

Comment: u'Unsupported special character for delimiter: \\]\\|\\['

Comment: Delimiter cannot be more than a single character